# Proving that $(\mu^{*})^{*}=\mu^*$ for a measure $\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am not sure I am using the standard definitions so I will open by
defining what I need:

> 1. Let $X$ be a set, $\nu:\, \mathscr{P}(X)\to[0,\infty]$ will be called an external measure if $\nu(\emptyset)=0$ and for any
>      $\{A_{i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}\subseteq\mathscr{P}(X)$ (not neccesarily disjoint) it
>      holds that
>      $\nu(\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_{i})\leq\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\nu(A_{i})$
> 2. Let $\nu$ be an external measure on a set $X$ then we say that a set $A$ is $\nu$ measurable if for any $E\subseteq X$: $\nu(E)=\nu(E\cap A)+\nu(E\cap A^{c})$

Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-additive measure on an algebra $A\subseteq X$, let $\mu^*$
be the outer measure on $X$ that comes from $\mu$.

It was proven in another exercise that the set of $\nu:=\mu^{*}$
measurable sets, $M$, is a $\sigma$ algebra and that $\nu$ is $\sigma$-additive
on $M$.

Since $\nu$ is also a measure on the algebra $M$ there is an outer
measure $\nu^*=(\mu^*)^{*}$.

The exercise wishes to prove that $(\mu^{*})^{*}=\mu^*$.

I don't really know how to even start here, what I first wanted to figure out is what is $M$. my intuition is that $A=M$ but I tried to prove it and couldn't start (I wrote the definitions but I couldn't see why if $B\in A$ it is $\nu$-measurable, not to mention the other direction which seems even harder).

Can someone please help me get started on this problem ? maybe a hint or an observation that might help me figure out what to do?

ADDED: by an outer measure that comes from a measure I mean $$\forall E\subseteq X:\,\nu(E):=Inf\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_{i})\,|\, A_{i}\in A,E\subseteq\cup A_{i}\}$$

Comment: One question. How do you define an outer measure on $X$ coming from a measure?

Comment: @ThomasE. - $\forall E\subseteq X:\,\nu(E):=Inf\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\nu(A_{i})\,|\, A_{i}\in A,E\subseteq\cup A_{i}\}$

Comment: @ThomasE. - hope this makes things clear now

Comment: Thanks, it does. Another question though. Did you mean to show that $(\mu^{\*})^{\*}=\mu^{\*}$? Or that $(\mu^{\*})^{\*}|_{A}=\mu$? As currently stated, the two set-functions are defined on different domains.

Comment: @ThomasE. - yes, thanks for the correction. I updated the question

Comment: Maybe [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/68031) gives you some ideas. I might think about writing an answer but lack of response [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/256628/) doesn't really motivate me...

Comment: @Belgi I assumed that you were referring to a sigma algebra in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\scr A$ be the $\sigma-$algebra on which $\mu$ is defined, and let $\scr M$ be the set of measurable sets of $\mu^*$.

**Claim:** $ \forall E\subseteq X[\mu^{**}(E)\leq\mu^*(E)]$

**Proof:** Note that $\scr A\subseteq\scr M$. Thus:
$\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_{i})\,|\,  E\subseteq\cup A_{i}, A_{i}\in  \scr{A}\}\subseteq$$\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_{i})\,|\,  E\subseteq\cup A_{i}, A_{i}\in  \scr{M}\}$,

Hence:

$\inf\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_{i})\,|\,  E\subseteq\cup A_{i}, A_{i}\in  \scr{A}\}\geq$$\inf\{\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_{i})\,|\,  E\subseteq\cup A_{i}, A_{i}\in  \scr{M}\}$

Now we proceed with the rest of the proof. Let $\epsilon>0$. Let $(A_i)_{i\in Z^+}$ be a sequence of sets in $\scr{M}$, such that $E\subseteq\cup_{i\in Z^+}A_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu^*(A_i)<\mu^{**}(E)+\epsilon$. For each $A_i$, we choose a sequence of sets $(A_{i,j})_{j\in Z^+}$ in $\scr A$ such that $ A_i\subseteq \cup_{j\in Z^+}A_{i,j}$ and $\sum_{j\in Z^+}\mu(A_{i,j})<\mu^*(A_i)+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i}}$. It follows that:
$$\sum_{i\in Z^+}\sum_{j\in Z^+}\mu(A_{i,j})\leq\sum_{i\in Z^+}[\mu^*(A_i)+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{i}}]=\sum_{i\in Z^+}\mu^*(A_i)+\epsilon\leq (\mu^{**}(E)+\epsilon)+\epsilon$$

Note that $(A_{i,j})_{i,j\in Z^+}$ is a countable sequence of elements of $\scr A$ whose union contains $E$. Therefore, $\mu^*(E)\leq\sum_{i\in Z^+}\sum_{j\in Z^+}\mu(A_{i,j})$. Hence:
$$\mu^*(E)\leq\mu^{**}(E)+2\epsilon$$
Since $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary positive number, we get $\mu^*(E)\leq\mu^{**}(E)$. We combine this with the previous claim to get $\mu^*(E)=\mu^{**}(E)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will review it later today